# Need to play a video for automation on safari mobile using appium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

```
public WebDriver wd;

@Test
public void testSearchPage() throws InterruptedException {

      wd.get("http://live.viddigo.com/#/video/100496?_k=224w4e");
      wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      WebElement video= wd.findElement(By.id("videoPlayer"));

      JavascriptExecutor js =( JavascriptExecutor) wd ;
      js.executeScript ( "wd.findElement(By.id(\"videoPlayer\")).play();");
}
```

On Running this code it shows wd not found, tried document too, But didn't worked.

Comment: Have you actually instantiated your WebDriver object? i.e. is there anything else after `public WebDriver wd` ?

Comment: Nop there is nothing, If need to run it in IOS emulator->safari, If i intiaite it with safari driver it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an element in a JavaScript injection, you need to provide it to `executeScript`. You can then access it in `arguments` in your script:

```
WebElement video = wd.findElement(By.id("videoPlayer"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].play();", video);
```